# RouteCollection.php line 179 issue

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4 with Apache and Ubuntu 14.04.

I am having a problem everytime I open my website (nocnocgroup.com). The logs I receive are:

```
{"code":404,"message":"","file":"\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170530\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/RouteCollection.php","line":179},
```

referer: http://nocnocgroup.com/css/home/style.css

And this is a log with trace of the exception.

```
{
"code": 404,
"message": "",
"file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/RouteCollection.php",
"line": 179,
"trace": [{
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Router.php",
    "line": 548,
    "function": "match",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\RouteCollection",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Router.php",
    "line": 527,
    "function": "findRoute",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Router.php",
    "line": 513,
    "function": "dispatchToRoute",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Foundation\\/Http\\/Kernel.php",
    "line": 176,
    "function": "dispatch",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 30,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/barryvdh\\/laravel-cors\\/src\\/HandleCors.php",
    "line": 36,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Pipeline\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 148,
    "function": "handle",
    "class": "Barryvdh\\\\Cors\\\\HandleCors",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 53,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Foundation\\/Http\\/Middleware\\/TransformsRequest.php",
    "line": 30,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Pipeline\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 148,
    "function": "handle",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TransformsRequest",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 53,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Foundation\\/Http\\/Middleware\\/TransformsRequest.php",
    "line": 30,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Pipeline\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 148,
    "function": "handle",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TransformsRequest",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 53,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Foundation\\/Http\\/Middleware\\/ValidatePostSize.php",
    "line": 27,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Pipeline\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 148,
    "function": "handle",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\ValidatePostSize",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 53,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Foundation\\/Http\\/Middleware\\/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
    "line": 46,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Pipeline\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 148,
    "function": "handle",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }, {}]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Routing\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 53,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Pipeline\\/Pipeline.php",
    "line": 102,
    "function": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\{closure}",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Foundation\\/Http\\/Kernel.php",
    "line": 151,
    "function": "then",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{}]
}, {
    "file": "\\/var\\/www\\/client\\/20170403\\/nocnoc\\/vendor\\/laravel\\/framework\\/src\\/Illuminate\\/Foundation\\/Http\\/Kernel.php",
    "line": 116,
    "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
    "class": "Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel",
    "type": "->",
    "args": [{
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }]
}]
}
```

I don't know where to start, as the exception trace is all Framework stuff, I don't know if it's a server problem (apache) or a coding problem (laravel). If you can help me it would be great.

Thank you very much

Comment: There must be some typo in your route. Check it.

Comment: you are not showing anything useful to debug

Comment: there is problem in you web.php file or in view file method...check it

Comment: Your page is trying to load a bunch of assets (several css files, like `/css/themes/orange-blue.css`, images and similar) that doesn't seem to exist. Go to your site, open up the browsers "developer tools", go to the "network" tab and update your page. Then you will see all the files that it's trying to load that doesn't exist.